# RowNumber() Over(Order By x) with a subquery not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pagination, row-number

The 'count' query runs fine. The 'Page of records' query runs fine as long as the commented section stays as-is. If uncommented it never returns... just keeps going. Any help on how to get past this would be greatly appreciated.

```
-- Page or records
DECLARE @p0 int;
DECLARE @p1 int;
SET @p0 = 100;
SET @p1 = 20;

SELECT DISTINCT ZIP_CODE, RowNum
FROM     ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ZIP_CODE) as RowNum, ZIP_CODE
           FROM   ODS.PHP1300_DWH.FACETS_MEMBER
           --WHERE LEFT(ZIP_CODE, 5) NOT IN (SELECT SHORT_ZIP_CODE 
                    --                     FROM DWH.Reference.R_ZIP_CODE)
         ) AS x
WHERE    RowNum BETWEEN @p0 + 1 AND @p0 + @p1
ORDER BY RowNum

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Count
SELECT COUNT(ZIP_CODE)
FROM   ODS.PHP1300_DWH.FACETS_MEMBER  
WHERE  LEFT(ZIP_CODE, 5) NOT IN (SELECT SHORT_ZIP_CODE 
                                 FROM   DWH.Reference.R_ZIP_CODE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your predicate in the derived table is just quite expensive. Hard to say without an execution plan. Here are a couple of measures you can take:

- Try making `LEFT(FACETS_MEMBER.ZIP_CODE, 5)` a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) and index it
- Be sure that `R_ZIP_CODE.SHORT_ZIP_CODE` has an index on it
- Be sure that `R_ZIP_CODE.SHORT_ZIP_CODE` has a `NOT NULL` constraint on it.

Apart from that, I think that your `DISTINCT` keyword in the outer query is useless, as you're adding the `RowNum`, which is distinct for every record anyway. So you should move `DISTINCT` into your nested query, which should use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`, as explained here:

http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/09/sql-trick-row_number-is-to-select-what-dense_rank-is-to-select-distinct/

Comment: @KeithMyers: Which one of these measures did the trick, finally?